# How to inject a single command into the powershell history?

Tags: powershell

If I have the following string defined in powershell ( or any other value for a valid command )

```
$foo = "Get-ChildItem -filter *.cmake"
```

How could I inject that string ( without executing the command ) into the powershell history so the next time the user presses the up arrow this command is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** -- Fixed setup as previous example provided did not work properly

There are two histories that will need to be updated for two different purposes.

**UP/DOWN Arrow PowerShell History**

Updating console host history will change what up/down arrow history display for any new Window PowerShell created

```
     Add-Content -path (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath "Get-ChildItem -filter *.cmake"
```

**PowerShell History**

Updating through Add-History will modify the history file that display history through Get-History

You can use the following command to add to history per documentation

```
 Add-History
   [[-InputObject] <PSObject[]>]
   [-Passthru]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Steps:

1. Create object of entry with proper keys expected by insert history
2. Add to array of objects that you want to insert
3. Call add history command and provide the array of objects in #2

Actual sample command using the one you provided in example

```
 PS C:\> $foo = [pscustomobject]@{
 >>     CommandLine        = "Get-ChildItem -filter *.cmake"
 >>     ExecutionStatus    = "Completed"
 >>     StartExecutionTime =  "8/31/2020  2:44:16 AM"
 >>     EndExecutionTime   = "8/31/2020  2:44:16 AM"
 >> }
 PS C:\> $commands = @()
 PS C:\> $commands += $foo
 PS C:\>  Add-History -InputObject $commands  -PassThru

   Id CommandLine
   -- -----------
   133 Get-ChildItem -filter *.cmake
```

The passthru is only necessary to display output inserted
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/add-history?view=powershell-7

Comment: That does not work.  Did you try it? The error returned is ``Add-History: Cannot add history because the input object has a format that is not valid.``

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, updated to properly add the history

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Also included the way to properly update the history file that gets used for up/down arrow in power shell

Answer (score 2):

While the options listed as part of the currently accepted answer all work partially, the objective stated in the question was never accomplished (at least when I tried to reproduce the accepted solution):

> How could I inject that string ( without executing the command ) into the powershell history so the next time the user presses the up arrow this command is available

While the approach via `Add-History` does append to the history as retrieved via `Get-History`, it does not affect the commands suggested when navigating back via the up arrow

Manually appending to the file under `(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath` does eventually affect the up-arrow history, but only after triggering a reaload (e.g. starting a new PS session)

This **integrated way of writing to the readline history did work** for me:

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AddToHistory("Write-Host `"I'm an artificially injected suggestion`"")
```